# Form with ajax doesn't send the email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, email

I'm trying to submit a form with ajax and it just doesn't work. The problem is that it actually tell me that it send the email, but when I check my email I got nothing. It seems to stop working when I call the Ajax method. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="form_contact" class="col_50">
    <input type="text" id="prenom_contact" name="prenom_contact" placeholder="Prénom" />
    <input type="text" id="nom_contact" name="nom_contact" placeholder="Nom" />
    <input type="text" id="email_contact" name="email_contact" placeholder="Courriel" />
    <textarea id="message_contact" name="message_contact" rows="6" placeholder="Votre message..."></textarea>

    <input type="submit" id="submit_contact" name="submit_contact" value="Envoyer" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
var prenom = $("#prenom_contact").val(),
    nom = $("#nom_contact").val(),
    email = $("#email_contact").val(),
    message = $("#message_contact").val();

var error_count = 0;

//THERE IS ADDITIONNAL CODE HERE WHO'S JUST CHECHKING IF THE VAR AREN'T EMPTY, I'M JUST NOT SHOWING IT BECAUSE I KNOW THAT IT IS WORKING

//IF THE FORM HAS NO ERROR
if(error_count === 0)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://davidstpierre.ca/new/form_contact.php",
            data: "prenom=" + prenom + "&nom=" + nom + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,               
        error: function() {
            alert("Une erreur est survenue. Veuillez actualiser la page de nouveau et réessayer.");
        },
        success: function() {
            //RESET THE FORM
            $('#prenom_contact').val('');
            $('#nom_contact').val('');
            $('#email_contact').val('');
            $('#message_contact').val('');

            alert("Good job!");
        }
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{   
    echo "<p id='contact_success'>Succès!</p>";

    $prenom = $_POST['prenom_contact'];
    $nom = $_POST['nom_contact'];
    $email = $_POST['email_contact'];   
    $message = $_POST['message_contact'];       

    $destinataire = "saintpierre.david@gmail.com";
    $titre_courriel = "Un nouveau message de la part de " .$prenom." ".$nom. " sur votre portfolio.";

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '.$prenom.' '. $nom .' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";

    $codehtml=
    "<html><body>" .
        "<p><strong>Nom:</strong> ".htmlspecialchars($nom)."</p>".
        "<p><strong>Prénom:</strong> ".htmlspecialchars($prenom)."</p>".
        "<p><strong>Adresse électronique:</strong> ".htmlspecialchars($email)."</p>".
        "<p><strong>Commentaires:</strong> ".htmlspecialchars($message)."</p><br>" .
    "</body></html>";

    if(!empty($nom) & !empty($prenom) & !empty($email) & !empty($message))
    {
        if(mail($destinataire, $titre_courriel, $codehtml, $headers))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you have an smtp server installed??

Comment: `return` in PHP doesn't do any output, so there's nothing to return BACK to the JS client. You need to output SOMETHING, like `echo 1` or `echo 0`, or even `echo json_encode(true)`. There'd be no way for a failed `mail()` call to tell the JS code anything, since there's no output. Beyond that, if it DOES return true, did you check your mail server's logs to see what happened after PHP handed over the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP code is looking for the following parameters:

1. prenom_contact
2. nom_contact
3. email_contact
4. message_contact

But you have the following for the ajax call:

```
data: "prenom=" + prenom + "&nom=" + nom + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message
```

Also, it is best to use an object so jQuery will encode for you:

```
data: {
    prenom_contact: prenom,
    nom_contact: nom,
    email_contact: email,
    message_contact: message
},
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I should have posted earlier I wasted so much time on this haha! :P